# VS Code - Keyboard Shortcut Run Everything in Paranthesis

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I use VS Code for data analysis with Python, mainly pandas, numpy, and a few plotting libraries. I have interactive mode enabled and can shift-enter on a selection to run the selection. This works well for data analysis.

I often chain many lines of analysis on a single dataframe into 5+ lines of code wrapped in parenthesis. In order to evaluate with shift enter, I have to select all of the lines of code. This involves a lot of manual scrolling while holding shift.

My question - is there a keyboard shortcut I can activate to select everything inside the outer-most parentheses and run? Or must I highlight the many line code to then hit shift enter?

Coming from Jupyter Lab, I could ctrl-enter to run the cell. Is there some similar setting I can activate in VS Code?

Comment: An alternative operation, try to use jupyter extension, and create an `.ipynb` file to run.

Comment: I think you're missing out on VS Code's [proper jupyter notebook functionality](https://code.visualstudio.com/learn/educators/notebooks). Check out this [step-by-step guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks). I think what you're using is different - just the base python extension in some `.py` file vs working with independently executable cells like Jupyer Lab/Notebooks.